# How to handle adding a close link within an UL/LI item

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've got some code like so:

```
<ul id="ulPersonal">
      <li class="break eTime">
        <p>Manage your time card.</p>
        <div id="dEtime">
          some content
        </div>
       </li>
</ul>
```

The div only appears once you hove over the `li` item, in jquery:

```
    $('#dEtime').hide(); //initially hide the div...

    //when the user hovers show the div
    $(".eTime").hover(function () {
        $('#dEtime').fadeIn('slow');
    });
```

So basically the page shows the li item, I hove over it and the div is shown.  Now I tried it so that when you "un-hover" off the li then the div disappears, however the UX was not friendly...to much flickering.

So I decided to add a close hyperlink...but if I add it within the li item and click on it, the div reappears as I am still "hovering" inside the li.  How can I handle this so that I can allow the user to close the div?

I've got a lot of seperate `ul` items that do this, so I dont want to add the close link after the ul, and obviously I cannot just add an `href` tag outside of an li, as that is just plain wrong.

Comment: "too much flickering", sounds like a positioning problem, and the right approach would probably be to fix that in your CSS ?

Comment: Can you create a demo in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/76BQ7/1/

Comment: Well I dont mean flickering, its just too much opening and closing and its a UX nightmare.  So its not a CSS issue.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Your fiddle is perfectly my issue.  Now I want a close hyperlink...but If I add the close hyperlink and `.hide()` the div it reappears because the close hyperlink is inside the `li` item.  Imagine a bunch of `ul` items with `li` items in them...I need a close hyperlink for each one...where can i place it so that jquery's hover event wont reopen the div...

Comment: @ArunPJohny - see my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76BQ7/9/

Comment: @oJM86o do not apply hover on your `close link` filter it out while applying hover. `:not(#closeIt)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [.mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) instead of [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) because since you are passing only one callback to `.hover()` it will be called for both mouse enter and leaving conditions

```
$('#dEtime').hide(); //initially hide the div...
$('#closeIt').hide(); //initially hide the div...

//when the user hovers show the div
$(".eTime").mouseenter(function () {
    $('#dEtime').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#closeIt').show(); //initially hide the div...
});

$("#closeIt").click( function(){
    $('#dEtime').hide(); //initially hide the div...
    $('#closeIt').hide();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sVSFA/)

Comment: P. Jonny - that is because you changed your content 3 times :).  I will look at this now.  Thanks

Comment: @oJM86o see the comments to see why

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29612/discussion-between-ojm86o-and-arun-p-johny)

Comment: arun can yuo join me in chat now I am running into another issue related to this.

Comment: @oJM86o yes, let me know the problem